# How does this __iter__ and __next__ algorithem work? How does it print all those prime numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

```
class PrimesBelow():
    def __init__(self,bound):
        self.candidate_numbers = list(range(2,bound))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.candidate_numbers) == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        next_prime = self.candidate_numbers[0]
        self.candidate_numbers = [x for x in self.candidate_numbers if x % next_prime != 0]
        return next_prime
primes_to_hundread = [prime for prime in PrimesBelow(100)]
print(primes_to_hundread)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Each time it returns another prime, it removes all the multiples of that prime from its candidates list. That way any non-primes are removed before they are reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the actual information is here:

```
[x for x in self.candidate_numbers if x % next_prime != 0]
```

which contain the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

The `__iter__` and `__next__` method, are special Python methods to have a class behave like an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).

Comment: But how does 2 get added in the list when 2 % 2 is zero??

Comment: `2` is on the original list. It is retrieved *before* all multiples of 2 are removed. On the next call, 3 is retrieved before all multiples of 3 are removed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For large (or possibly infinite) bounds, a more (memory-)efficient implemention would use generators:

```
from itertools import count
from math import gcd


class Sieve:
    def __init__(self, bound=None):
        self.candidates = count(2) if bound is None else iter(range(2, bound))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        prime = next(self.candidates)
        self.candidates = filter(lambda x, d=prime: x % d != 0, self.candidates)
        return prime
```

When `Sieve` is first instantiated, the `candidates` attribute is a sequence of integers starting with 2.

`__next__` has one precondition: the first element of the `candidates` attribute must be a prime number. This is satisfied by the first call because `2` is a prime number.

`__next__` then

1. Removes the first element from `candidates` and calls it `prime`
2. Replaces `candidates` with a new iterable that consists only of those former candidates that are *not* divisible by `prime`.

These two actions fulfill the precondition for the next call to `__next__`, as the `i`th call to `__next__` removes all numbers divisible by the `i`th prime number. Thus each remaining candidate is not divisible by any previously seen prime number.

Comment: This does not work when specifying `bound`, since `range()` is not an Iterator. You should replace it with `iter(range())`.

Comment: Also the infinite bound is purely theoretical, since for `bound` as low as `8000` (in a standard Python installation) you would hit the `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`  error, due to the fact that each generator is spawning a new generator. This happens regardless of whether a `bound` is specified or not.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using `filter` and a user-defined function, but I guess I can't.